# Energy efficient spin loop

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86, x86-64

I am writing a spin loop that monitors changes of a global variable. This has a side effect of occupying an entire CPU core, which is fine since I am using a multi-core machine.

My question is: can it be made energy efficient? I am using C++ and have access to x64 assembly if needed.

Here is my code:

```
void monitor_changes(int*variable_to_monitor){
    int last_value=*variable_to_monitor;
    while(1){ //this is the spin loop - don't want the os to interrupt it, but can it be energy efficient?
        int cur_value=*variable_to_monitor;
        if (*variable_to_monitor!=last_value){
            printf("value has changed!");
            last_value=cur_value;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I don't want to use the OS services for that because the monitoring needs to react as quickly as possible. Using OS services would introduce delay.

Comment: C++11? Then `std::condition_variable` will fit your purpose. However, note that `variable_to_monitor` isn't secured by a mutex or atomic operations (probably). Since `condition_variable` needs a mutex either way, you can use the same mutex to secure `variable_to_monitor`.

Comment: Depends why you want a spin loop. If it's because you're warming up soup for lunch on your CPU heat sink then no, it can't be made more efficient, heat is heat. If you're doing this for some programming reason then there might be a better way to achieve it than spinning (one that avoids undefined behavior due to data races, for starters). In that case making your spin cooler would only be half a fix.

Comment: @SteveJessop well, we could have it detect the soup prior to warming up. (which, amusingly, is similar to Zeta's suggestion: spurious wakeups means that it still needs to probe the variable)

Comment: @Yakk: true, I was assuming manual intervention to start and stop the program as required ;-)

Comment: You could throw in `pause` instruction, this is what it's for.

Comment: Instead of spinning why not have a the other thread signal a wake up when it modifies it?

Comment: Interrupts & signals are more efficient than polling / spinning.

Comment: Try usleep(1) or the equivalent for your os. In the worst case you'll start sleeping just as the value updates and thus you'll be 1 microsecond late.

Comment: @yigalirani: If this is for hardware, a CPU interrupt is the right way to get fast response. If its responding to another thread you should use an OS function. Pretty much the only real-life reason I've ever seen code like yours is in malware or DRM-break exploits...wait for the right program state then blast it. Is that what you're doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a very unusual use case, your approach is wrong. You should not be using a spin loop to monitor changes to a global variable. Instead, you should signal to the watcher that the global has changed. If using pthreads, look at `pthread_cond_signal` and `pthread_cond_wait`. Various C++ libraries have these too, for instance Boost has mutexes and condition variables. An old fashioned way to do it is with a pipe, selecting on the pipe in your monitor, and writing one character when you change the global.

If you really do need to monitor a global, you could consider sleeping between checks (how soon do you need to know), consider whether your OS has something that causes a schedule to occur, or consider the `pause` instruction - see:
 http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_232.html

Comment: The pause instruction is ,indeed, what i was looking for. thanks. I cant use threading because the i need extremely fast reaction time.

Comment: @yigalirani If so, then you're doing it *all* wrong. For example, you say you need extremely fast reaction time, yet your code bone-headedly takes the mother of all mispredicted branches as soon as the event you claim you need to react quickly to occurs, blowing out the pipelines and putting performance in the toilet. If you actually need quick response, why does your code go out of its way to respond as slowly as possible?

Comment: David, if you are referring to the printf, then it is not what the production code is doing - it is there just to make the code simpler. also, I have tested the above code,with the addition of the pause instruction, and is is looping .25 billion a second. that means that it can react within 4 ns. That is wicked fast and a lot faster than any OS-assisted code. Of course, further testing is needed.

Answer (score 2):

If fast response times are important, take a close look at what is possible given your OS and services. In best effort computers (vs real time) resolution is typically around 10msec no matter what fields indicate. Additionally, OS servicing takes time that set a lower bound on how fast your code can react.

Unless you have written your own low-level driver for specialized equipment, I doubt you are getting resolutions much better than 10msec.

Spin loops are never good for energy efficiency. In modern processors there are idle/sleep states (C0, C1, etc) that put the processor to sleep when not used. The latency to wake up from these idle states is on the order of usec. This is less by orders of magnitude than the latency introduced by OS drivers, libraries and code generated by conventional compilers. Note that the important word here is "not used". These sleep states do not impact performance in any meaningful way since the processor is not doing anything anyway.

I've done some writing on this subject. Take a look at the references in [List of Useful Power and Power Management Articles, Blogs and References](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/list-of-useful-power-and-power-management-articles-blogs-and-references). (It is embarrassingly biased toward my material. As time goes on, this will change.)

Here are my more concrete suggestions:

(1) Determine the realistic response times you need. 
    (a) If it is to respond to human input, you can't get meaningful response times less than a quarter of a sec.
    (b) If it is to respond to machine generated events, you'll need to analyze not only the minimum delta between events, but also the statistical variance introduced by communication mechanisms, e.g. network protocols.

(2) Determine what your system is capable of doing. This is pretty hard to get unless you have specialized real-time equipment, e.g. RTOS, specialized libraries and drivers. You may need to do some experiments and data collection.

(3) Figure out what equipment you really want to achieve the response times you need.

Now let’s get down to some reality. Since you asked this question, I'm guessing that you are not working with real-time equipment needing specialized and expensive OSs, libraries, etc. I suspect you are using a conventional multicore computer using a standard OS (Linux, Windows, OSX, Android, etc), standard libraries and a general purpose compiler (e.g. gcc). I doubt you can get resolutions <10msec, and I suspect you need response times at best around 100msec, even higher if you are depending upon human input.

Do not use a spin loop. This is the worst thing you can do from an energy efficiency perspective since it prevents the processor from going into an idle state. Non-idle processor power can be >30Watts. Idle power can be <5W with latencies <100usec. If you use a spin loop, your power consumption will be >30Watts. If you allow the use of idle states, your overall power consumption will be likely <10Watts with no significant performance impact.

Wake up every 50msec to 100msec to check for a change in your variable, then go back to sleep.

### Regards

Taylor

PS You asked a good question. There is a lot of misunderstanding concerning this topic in the field. I can’t mention the well-known applications that have made this same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Another option besides the pause instruction is MONITOR/MWAIT.  It might be too high latency for what you're looking for, but give it a read anyways:

http://semipublic.comp-arch.net/wiki/Monitor-Mwait

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-use-the-monitor-and-mwait-streaming-simd-extensions-3-instructions

https://blogs.oracle.com/dave/resource/mwait-blog-final.txt